# Overdue by -10 which means overdue by 10 minutes. Swap the '-10' to overdue by 10 minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case-when

```
CASE WHEN Color LIKE '%RED%' THEN (10 - (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Calltime,GETDATE())))
```

Sometimes might give a -10 value. My question is when I get a value <0, how can I change that value to 10 minutes overdue.

Comment: Please show sample data and expected results.

Comment: What is the logic that you want to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest CASE statements, but since you're now introducing text to the integer value, you'll have to cast all output to string:

```
CASE WHEN Color LIKE '%RED%' THEN
    CASE WHEN (10 - (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Calltime,GETDATE()))) >= 0 THEN CAST((10 - (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Calltime,GETDATE()))) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    ELSE CAST(ABS((10 - (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Calltime,GETDATE())))) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ' minutes overdue'
    END
ELSE -- Additional SQL for when color is not red
END
```

Comment: <pedantry> It's a [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) _expression_, not _statement_. </pedantry>

Answer (score 0):

Just use another CASE END inside the CASE. Try this:

```
CASE WHEN Color LIKE '%RED%' THEN (CASE WHEN (10 - (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Calltime,GETDATE()))) < 0 THEN 10 ELSE (10 - (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Calltime,GETDATE()))) END)
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to calculate the common value in a `lateral join` rather than repeating my logic multiple times.

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (CallTime DATETIME, Color VARCHAR(12));

INSERT INTO @Test (Color, CallTime)
SELECT 'RED', DATEADD(MINUTE, -5, GETDATE())
UNION ALL SELECT 'RED', DATEADD(MINUTE, -12, GETDATE())
UNION ALL SELECT 'BLUE', DATEADD(MINUTE, -5, GETDATE());

SELECT
    CASE WHEN T.Color LIKE '%RED%' THEN
        CASE WHEN C.CallDifference >= 0 THEN CAST(C.CallDifference AS VARCHAR(MAX))
        ELSE CAST(ABS(C.CallDifference) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ' minutes overdue'
        END
    ELSE 'BLUE'
    END
FROM @Test T
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(10 - (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,T.Calltime,GETDATE())))) as C (CallDifference);
```

Thanks to e_i_pi for the logic code.